# for loop for assigning accounts to names in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to create a pretty simple for loop in order to update a dataframe. I'm not sure if this is best practice or there is another way to do it. I have a list of names, and a list of accounts and I'm trying to assign each account to the name with the lowest value.

Here's what I have:

```
Person <- c("Jeff", "Cindy", "Matt", "Jessica")
TotalValue <- c(54, 46, 15, 13)
NAMES <- data.frame(Person, TotalValue)

Accounts <- c(paste0("acc",1:50))
AccountValues <- c(1:50)
ACCOUNTS <- data.frame(Accounts, AccountValues)

for (i in nrow(ACCOUNTS)){
  idx <- which.min(NAMES$TotalValue)
  NAMES$TotalValue[idx] <- NAMES$TotalValue[idx] + ACCOUNTS$AccountValues[i]
  ACCOUNTS$name[i] <- as.character(NAMES$Person[idx])
  }
```

Starting Point:

```
Person   TotalValue
Jeff     54
Cindy    46
Matt     15
Jessica  13

Accounts   AccountValues   Person
Acc1       1
Acc2       2
Acc3       3
Acc4       4
Acc5       5
```

etc.

I'm trying to iterate through each of the 50 accounts, and assign one of the People from the NAMES df. I want it to find the person with the lowest score, and assign that name. 
Acc1 would look at the 4 names and see that Jessica has the lowest score of 13. It then populates the Person column for Acc1 with Jessica's name, and also give the AccountValue of 1, from acc1, to Jessica's score making her score now 14. It then looks at Acc2, and finds Jessica again since her score is 14 which is still the lowest. Again it populates Acc2 Person to Jessica. For acc3 it would find Matt because Jessica's score is now 16 (13 + 1 + 2), and Matt's is only 15. It would then populate Matt's name in the Person column for Acc3 and add 3 to his score giving him 18.. and so on and so forth.

I've shortened the list to Acc1 - Acc5 instead of 50. And this would be the result after the 5 accounts were assigned.

Expected Result:

```
Person   TotalValue
Jeff     54
Cindy    46
Matt     23
Jessica  20

Accounts   AccountValues   Person
Acc1       1               Jessica
Acc2       2               Jessica
Acc3       3               Matt
Acc4       4               Jessica
Acc5       5               Matt
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please show the expected result.

Comment: @Roland I edited it to show current and expected. Thanks!

Comment: Please explain more of assignment logic. How do we map *Person* to *Account*? And how is his different from your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41967792/function-that-iterates-and-assigns-based-on-value-in-r)?

Comment: This is identical to my last question I posted but I was trying to reframe it. 

I'm trying to take a list of accounts and assign the name to it which has the lowest score. That score is then augmented by the account value, and the process repeats. In my example, Jessica has the lowest score so acc1 which is worth 1 will get assigned to her bumping her from 13 to 14. acc2 also goes to Jessica because with 14 she is still at the lowest of the names, and that would change her score to 16. acc3 then would go to Matt because Matt has 15, and Jessica has 16. That would increase Matt's score to 18

Comment: @Parfait I edited the question, and also responded above. I hope that gives more clarity to the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @Parfait I actually just realized what I did wrong. The answer I received on the last question was correct, I just found my mistake when trying to implement it. Sorry for the duplication and thank you!